# Twilio API always sending SMS always as alphanumeric

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We have been using the API to send 2 types of SMS, sometimes we send as a number and sometimes we send as an alphanumeric. Until now the API is the same except we change the From value in the API from our Twilio number to the Alphanumeric Sender ID that we register, we do the API as documentation, when we want the number for the user to reply back:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json" \
--data-urlencode "Body=Hi there" \
--data-urlencode "From=+15017122661" \
--data-urlencode "To=+15558675310" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

and when we use our alphasender ID:

```
--data-urlencode "From=MyCompany..." \
```

But we receive an email warning from Twilio, that for compliance we need to re-register the sender ID, so we did. After that all the SMS regardless of using FROM=+123 or FROM=MyCompany they are all sent with MyCompany, why is that, is there a new API that I am not aware of that i need to use to get the SMS sent from a phone number?

Also:

- If i use FROM=blabla which is a SenderID invalid and that I never rerequested, the SMS still send on behalf of the sender ID I registered,
- If i use messagingServiceId, and FROM is empty, I still get from SenderID

Answer (score 1):

> When you send SMS messages to a country where Alphanumeric Sender IDs
> are not supported, Twilio will use a regular phone number from your
> messaging service.

So in your case, you might be sending to a country that doesn't support Alphanumeric (like the US). The number would show up as `FROM=+123` instead of `FROM=MyCompany`.

If you're unsure about which countries support Alphanumeric Sender ID, check out this [list of countries](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID).

Reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-alphanumeric-sender-id

Comment: Hi, I probably didnt explain myself we have been using twilio API for a few years now (about 5), and we have been sending both type of SMS from a number and also from Alphanumeric, since twilio requetsed us to reregister the alphanumeric as been part of their complaince, all our messages goes as alphanumeric, regardless of sending them as a number